# Maven build fails with Java 8 and JUnit 5

Tags: java, maven, java-8, build, junit5

I have a Java project that uses Java 8. I want to use JUnit 5. I'm using Eclispe. If I add the JUnit 5 library in the project's Build Path, the build is successful inside Eclipse. However, when I build with Maven at command line it fails.

```
    Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
    Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
    Java version: 1.8.0_241, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program 
    Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre
```

Below the pom.xml. I've tried other versions of pom found in Google search, but all gave me the same errors.
UPDATE:
If I remove `<scope>test</scope>`from pom.xml, the build still fails.

```
<properties>
    <!-- Dependency versions -->
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <!-- Java 8 -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- Encoding -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>
  <!-- Jupiter API for writing tests -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <!-- Maven Surefire plugin to run tests -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
       <!-- plugin to run test cases from maven -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Maven plugin to use perticular java version to compile code -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

```
[INFO] 5 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.473 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-28T12:19:11-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project Java8: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Users\Documents\Java8\src\main\java\com\name\stream\ClassName.java:[8,23] error: package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Documents\Java8\src\main\java\com\name\stream\ClassName.java:[8] error: static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] C:\Users\Documents\Java8\src\main\java\com\name\stream\ClassName.java:[31,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method assertEquals(Optional<String>,Optional<Object>)
[ERROR]   location: class ClassName
[ERROR] C:\Users\Documents\Java8\src\main\java\com\name\stream\ClassName.java:[33,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method assertEquals(Optional<Optional<String>>,Optional<Object>)
[ERROR]   location: class ClassName
[ERROR] C:\Users\Documents\Java8\src\main\java\com\name\stream\ClassName.java:[44,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method assertEquals(Optional<String>,Optional<Object>)
[ERROR]   location: class ClassName
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The imports for JUnit Jupiter are from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` and not from `org.junit`? Furthermore you are trying having a test in `src/main/java` which will not work cause you have defined the dependency for junit jupiter in scope test which means you have to have a unit test in `src/test/java` location and named like `*Test.java` and not in `src/main/java`...

Comment: The build is successful inside the Eclipse, this is the import statement I have inside Eclipse which uses the JUnit 5 libraries: 

     import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

If I remove the <scope>test</scope>, the build still fails.

Comment: Eclipse does not correctly separate test scope and compile scope dependencies so keep the scope test which is correct. You have to create a Test class in `src/test/java/com/name/stream/ClassNameTest.java` and use the appropriate annotations which needs to be from `org.junit.jupiter.api` package.

Comment: Take a look at this example project: https://github.com/khmarbaise/basic-junit-jupiter-test (Simple Test case and assertions also simple class with a single method just to show how it works..)...It builds on command line, in IDEA Intellij and should also work in Eclipse and works on GitHub Actions...

Comment: When I created the Test class and compiled, the build was successful. Please add your response in the answer section if you will, that I can accept it. I may have a Java code - in the 'scr/main' that uses some classes from JUnit 5 library, I know that its not the best practice but... do you know how pom needs to be modified that build does not fail? Removing test scope is not the solution as you mentioned.

Comment: Using JUnit Juniter in src/main/java is usually wrong...except you are writing an extension/listener etc. for JUnit Jupiter which I assume is not the case. Do not try to fight against convention over configuration paradigm.

Comment: If you already know that's not best practice why violating it? What is the reason? please explain more in detail?

Comment: B/c I thought if the build is successful in Eclipse, there should be a way that maven gives me a successful build as well. Like if I add a dependency to pom for maven, it recognizes the library and compiles with no error no matter which package/directory the code resides in.

Comment: Also the build in Eclipse is successful and its not on maven, so shouldn't you say: "Maven does not correctly separate test scope and compile scope..."?

Comment: 1/2 Maven correctly separates the scope. You can realize  with other IDE's they are working correctly in contradiction to Eclipse also seen the issue related to other build tools (Eclipse says Ok) but other tools say wrong as well...There is one more thing to see. If you are working with a build tool the IDE is no longer the truth. It's the build tool. In this case Maven.  The build in your pom describes what is build which is different from what Eclipse makes out of it..and that sometimes confuses people (apart from simply wrong).

Comment: 2/2 In maven you said to use junit jupiter in scope test which means you can't use it in `src/main/java` which the build exactly shows...Eclipse doesn't ?...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212724/discussion-between-bluesky-and-khmarbaise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does not correctly separate test scope and compile scope dependencies so keep the scope test which is correct. You have to create a Test class in 
`src/test/java/com/name/stream/ClassNameTest.java` and use the appropriate annotations which needs to be from `org.junit.jupiter.api` package

Take a look at this example project: github.com/khmarbaise/basic-junit-jupiter-test (Simple Test case and assertions also simple class with a single method just to show how it works..)...It builds on command line, in IDEA Intellij and should also work in Eclipse and works on GitHub Actions

Comment: Eclipse supports separation of main and test scopes since Photon (2018) - see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#jdt-test-sources . @blueSky please take a look at your project configuration in Eclipse. Under Java Build Path, is `src/test/java` marked as "Contains test source"? Also, how exactly is the JUnit dependency configured in Eclipse?